# C# search for repeating byte patterns in a binary file

Tags: c#, multithreading, file, binary

I am trying to search for repeating byte patterns in a very big binary file (always bigger than 4Gb).
The idea is to read *X* bytes (patternSize) based on an increasing *offset* in each iteration and then search from *offset+patternSize* the rest of the file for the same byte pattern. All of this using threads.

This is the code I've tried:

```
using System.Threading;

namespace pattern_search
{

    public class ThreadData
    {
        public FileStream Stream { get; set; }
        public byte[] SearchPattern { get; set; }
        public int PatternOffset { get; set; }
        public int PatternSize { get; set; }

        public ThreadData(FileStream stream, byte[] searchPattern, int patternOffset, int patternSize)
        {
            Stream = stream;
            SearchPattern = searchPattern;
            PatternOffset = patternOffset;
            PatternSize = patternSize;
        }
    }
    internal class Program
    {

        static void CompareTask(Object stateInfo)
        {
            ThreadData threadData = (ThreadData)stateInfo;
            long len = threadData.Stream.Length;
            for (int searchOffset = threadData.PatternOffset + threadData.PatternSize; searchOffset < (len - threadData.PatternSize); searchOffset++)
            {
                byte[] comparePattern = new byte[threadData.PatternSize];
                threadData.Stream.Seek(searchOffset, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                int readBytes = threadData.Stream.Read(comparePattern, 0, threadData.PatternSize); // Randomly throws exception
                if (comparePattern == threadData.SearchPattern)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Pattern: {0} Search: {1}", threadData.PatternOffset, searchOffset);
                }
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int patternSize = 8;
            String inputFilename = @"F:\Dev\log\data.bin";
            FileStream fs = new(inputFilename, FileMode.Open);
            long len = fs.Length;
            Console.WriteLine(len);
            for (int patternOffset = 0; patternOffset < (len - patternSize); patternOffset++)
            {
                byte[] searchPattern = new byte[patternSize];
                fs.Seek(patternOffset, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                int readBytes = fs.Read(searchPattern, 0, patternSize); // Randomly throws exception
                ThreadData data = new ThreadData(fs, searchPattern, patternOffset, patternSize);
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(CompareTask, data);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Every time I run this, the following exception is thrown at random offsets in the lines where I read the bytes from the file and I don't know why:

`System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.'`

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT**

- Very big file > 4Gb
- Using locks makes it very slow
- Using one FileStream (with FileShare.Read) for each Thread solves the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stream are not thread safe, to fix this using current algorithm you should use lock...

```
        static void CompareTask(Object stateInfo)
        {
            //...
                int readBytes;
                lock (threadData.Stream)
                {
                    threadData.Stream.Seek(searchOffset, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    readBytes = threadData.Stream.Read(comparePattern, 0, threadData.PatternSize); // Randomly throws exception
                }
            //...
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //...
                int readBytes;
                lock (fs)
                {
                    fs.Seek(patternOffset, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    readBytes = fs.Read(searchPattern, 0, patternSize); // Randomly throws exception
                }
            //.. 
        }
```

of course it would not be efficient now, if possible, load the entire file into memory and do operation directly on the buffer, at not lock cost.

Comment: Or just make one FileStream per thread.